# jQuery snippet doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've tried this jquery snippet in jsfiddle and it works perfectly fine, but when I insert this to a brand new html file, it doesn't work at all. It just shows "plain", while the exact same code shows "plain100" in jsfiddle which is what I want. What's the problem?

Code:

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var string = "100";
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
            a[0].innerHTML += string;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     

    
    <span>plain</span>
```

Comment: You haven't ended your `$(document).ready( ` - your last line should be `})`.

Comment: Oh sorry, saw your edit now. Thanks a lot, silly mistake by me. Fixed it and it works.

Comment: Also, I'd advise against using the word `string` as a variable name. It is reserved and could cause you errors down the road. Seeing as the missing `)` fixed your issue, I'm going to vote to close this question. *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error.**"*