# Code snippet works but not in my html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So basically, I've been looking at different questions and found a code snippet that worked perfectly in the snippet run. But when I copied it into my HTML file, it doesn't work.

My apologies if I sound like an idiot I'm a bit of a biggener.

I've checked other questions including
[jQuery snippet doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794771/jquery-snippet-doesnt-work)
and [Code works in Codepen, but not with my desktop files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402675/code-works-in-codepen-but-not-with-my-desktop-files)

But still couldn't seem to find a solution.

My code is as follows.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newsletter').on('click', '#newsletterButtonSubmit', function() {
      var inputVal = $(this).parent('div').find('#newsletterInputEmail').val();
      console.log(inputVal);
    });
  });
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newsletter">
  <div class="newsletter">
    <h6 class="headerDIV">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h6>
    <input id="newsletterInputEmail" class="input-email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here">
    <button id="newsletterButtonSubmit" width="100px" class="w3-button w3-round-xlarge w3-grey">Submit</button>
    <p><label id="newsletterEmailMSG" class="textFillField">This field is mandatory</label></p>
    <p><input id="newsletterCheckbox" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"><label class="textRights">I have read and accepted the general terms and conditions*</label></p>
    <p><label id="newsletterCheckboxMSG" class="textFillField">This field is mandatory</label></p>
    <label class="textRights2">See our <a href="politics/privacy/politica_de_privacidade_pt.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">Privacy Notice</a> for more information.</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I open the file in my browser, the script part doesn't work at all. It does nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!
:)

Comment: You need to include a reference to jQuery.js in the page, right before your `<script>` tag. See the examples on the jQuery site: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Check your browser console (F12, select console) - there should be an error `$ is not defined`

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` must be placed *before* your script using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Next to the order of loading, you have forgot the thing that the variable $ is not defined

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Full example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#newsletter').on('click', '#newsletterButtonSubmit', function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).parent('div').find('#newsletterInputEmail').val();
        console.log(inputVal);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Not sure that's what `.noConflict()` is for - you're essentially saying `$=$`

Comment: Since he using var $. Many libraries do use variable $. as per jquery: noConflict() method to give control of the $ variable back to whichever library first implemented it. This helps us to make sure that jQuery doesn't conflict with the $ object of other libraries. // Import other Library // Import jQuery Library $. noConflict(); // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.

Comment: If you used `var a = jquery.noConflict()` then sure, it gives `$` back to whatever it was before, but no - you've used `var $ = ` so you've given $ back then assigned $ immediately back as jquery.  The issue is that your `var $` is *global scope* - if it was inside a function or an iife or so, then sure.  But as it is, you've literally done `$=$`.  All off topic anyway as OPs problem was that jquery.js was after the code

Comment: Wait... you're saying `$` is defined as something else already?  Hence the `$ not defined` misunderstanding?  So you're *redefining* it back to `$` so it can be used?     ie  `var x = jQuery.noConflit()` `$(function...` "$ not defined" - that *does* make sense - but not the issue here